# Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array error

Tags: php, mysqli

I just learned mysqli since Mysql_ queries is deprecated and people keep telling me to use mysqli instead

so for starter I make a simple code to connect, insert and show data
I have no problem making connection, inserting data to database but I cannot show the data using mysqli_fetch_array

here is my code :

```
<?php
 $sql=("SELECT * from data_orang");
 $hasil=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  while(mysqli_fetch_array($hasil)){
  echo "nama : $hasil[nama] <br>
      umur : $hasil[umur] <br>
      kelamin : $hasil[kelamin] <br>";
  }
 ?>
```

this is what I've tried

```
   echo " nama : $hasil['nama'] <br>
          umur : $hasil['umur'] <br>
          kelamin : $hasil['kelamin'] <br>
```

I also tried adding `mysqli_assoc` and `mysqli_free_result($hasil)` but it does not work

Comment: I use procedural since I'm used to it, if you want to give answer please give it using procedural style

I haven't tried the object-oriented style yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its says: "Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array error". You have to create an array from result.

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil)){
  echo "nama : $result[nama] <br>
      umur : $result[umur] <br>
      kelamin : $result[kelamin] <br>";
  }
```

Comment: thank you. it worked. so it is different from the old mysql query

Comment: your welcome and old mysql_* extension was same too...
row = mysql_fetch_array($query)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the fetch array to an array variable. I this is common both in mysql and mysqli.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil)){
  echo "nama : ".$row ['nama'] ."<br>
      umur : ". $row ['umur'] ."<br>
      kelamin :". $row ['kelamin'] ."<br>";
  }
```